# Forbidden - CSRF token invalid

Tags: go

I want to pass a token in headers but when I send a request my token is always null.

This is how I connect csrf in main

```
csrfMiddleware := csrf.Protect([]byte("qwnbjb13jbhb12j3bjbbj"))
mainRouter.Use(csrfMiddleware)

serverPort := ":" + os.Getenv("SERVER_PORT")
logs.Logger.Info("starting server at ", serverPort)

err = http.ListenAndServe(serverPort, mainRouter)
if err != nil {
    logs.LogFatal(logs.Logger, "main", "main", err, "Failed to start server")
}
    logs.Logger.Info("server stopped")
}
```

Here I try to write in header

```
func NewAuthHandler(authMwRouter *mux.Router, mainRouter *mux.Router, u domain.AuthUsecase) {
    handler := &AuthHandler{
        AuthUsecase: u,
    }

    mainRouter.HandleFunc("/api/v1/auth/login", handler.Login).Methods(http.MethodPost, http.MethodOptions)
    mainRouter.HandleFunc("/api/v1/auth/register", handler.Register).Methods(http.MethodPost, http.MethodOptions)
}

func (a *AuthHandler) Register(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("X-CSRF-Token", csrf.Token(r))
```

And when I send a request, I always get 403

> URL: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/register
>
> Method: POST
>
> Status code: 403 Forbidden ( service worker)
>
> URL : strict-origin-when-cross-origin
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,OPTIONS
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
>
> Content-Length: 31
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>
> Date: Mon, 06 Nov 2023 11:27:57 GMT
>
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>
> Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
>
> Referer: http://localhost/
>
> Sec-Ch-Ua: "Chromium";v="118", "Google Chrome";v="118", "Not=A?
>
> Brand";v="99"
>
> Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
>
> Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "macOS"
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)
>
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0
>
> Safari/537.36
>
> X-Csrf-Token: null